# Generic Types Related But Incompatible

Tags: java, generics

Still trying to grasp the Generics concept...
The line

```
public interface FileStructure<L extends FileStructureLevel<L>, R extends FileStructureResource> extends NodeStructure<L, R>
```

gives following message:

```
type argument L#1 is not within bounds of type-variable L#2
  where L#1,L#2 are type-variables:
    L#1 extends FileStructureLevel<L#1> declared in interface FileStructure
    L#2 extends NodeStructureLevel<L#2> declared in interface NodeStructure
```

Now, this would seem trivial, as the type bounds are different. However, what is confusing is that actually, I am just narrowing the bound, since

```
public interface FileStructureLevel<E extends FileStructureLevel> extends NodeStructureLevel<FileStructureLevel>
```

so whatever `L1` is, it is certainly going to extend `L2`.
Why the mismatch? Anyone?

Further, given the declaration

```
public interface NodeStructure<L extends NodeStructureLevel<L>, R extends NodeStructureResource>
```

and

```
public class FileStructureResource implements NodeStructureResource<File>
```

why doesn't the first line produce similar error related to `R`, like below:

```
type argument R#1 is not within bounds of type-variable R#2
  where R#1,R#2 are type-variables:
    R#1 extends FileStructureResource declared in interface FileStructure
    R#2 extends NodeStructureResource declared in interface NodeStructure
```

Comment: Please show the declarations of all these classes: I think you're missing `NodeStructureResource` and more importantly `NodeStructureLevel`.

Comment: Also, make sure to fix any raw types, for example `FileStructureLevel<E extends FileStructureLevel>` should be `FileStructureLevel<E extends FileStructureLevel<E>>` - that may in fact be the issue.

Comment: Wouldn't `L extends FileStructureLevel<L>` be some kind of weird recursive generic typing? Am I missing something?

Comment: jpmc26, that's because it's going to be implemented by en Enum type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code

```
public interface FileStructureLevel<E extends FileStructureLevel>
    extends NodeStructureLevel<FileStructureLevel>
```

to

```
public interface FileStructureLevel<E extends FileStructureLevel>
    extends NodeStructureLevel<E>
```

and everybody will be happy. As it stands, a `FileStructureLevel<L>` is *not* a `NodeStructureLevel<L>` as required by `NodeStructure`, but is instead a `NodeStructureLevel<FileStructureLevel>`. This is what the compiler is trying to tell you.